# Map from a Sequence of Options

Tags: scala

How do i return a map from the following piece of  input:

```
val sources =  getSources() //returns Seq[Option[String]]
```

Now I am trying to return a map , where key is every valid string from this sequence.

```
sources.collect{ case Some(source) =>
val dates = ... some function using source .... // returns a List[LocalDate]
if dates.nonEmpty (source -> dates) else ???

}.toMap
```

Obviously this wont compile owing to the void else condition.
How do I return a map for ONLY those valid 'source' for which 'dates' is a valid non-empty List

Comment: I would simply return `(source -> dates)` and add extra `.filter((source, dates) => dates.nonEmpty)` step: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JLnh4TeSTpir54AAsN62Ww

Comment: One note: the `???` in Scala will compile but cause a runtime exception as you can see here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/17c0c74ae078431f70bbd68e3442255ca80a23e7/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L340-L344

Comment: Strangely this does not compile for me - the .filter((source, dates) => dates.nonEmpty) fails compilation .

Comment: @IUnknown what error do you get? Can yo reproduce your problem in a **Scastie**? Lesiak code is what I would write based on the details provided on your question.

Comment: .filter(_._2.nonEmpty).toMap working fine though

Comment: Oh right, tuple stuff in **Scala 2**, glad you fihured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
val sources =  getSources().flatten
val results = sources.zip(sources.map(src2dates)).filter(_._2.nonEmpty).toMap
```